# How to always show a command

Tags: command-line

When I enter a search it shows me the input in the command bar, for example:

[image]

However, when I enter in a command from the command history, for example clicking enter on line 50:

[image]

It doesn't shown any visual indicator that the string being searched is "Hello". Is there a way to make it such that all commands show up in the command-bar at the bottom?

Comment: You could try `<C-c>`; sometimes that puts the current text in the command-line for me

Comment: @D.BenKnoble that works and is great, thank you!

Comment: Ah! At first read I didn't get that you meant the `'incsearch'` feature that highlights matches as you type search terms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`<C-c>`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#E199) in any of the command-line windows puts the current line into the command-line, just like I'd never left. This re-enables things like `hlsearch` and other features.